# Mercurial under IIS7 (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: iis-7, mercurial

I have tried to install Mercurial under IIS7 like described here http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2010/04/08/Setting-up-Mercurial-server-in-IIS7-using-a-ISAPI-module.aspx I did each step and looked like very simple. but when I call http://localhost:81/ I'm getting next error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed
>   because an internal server error has occurred.
>
> > Detailed Error Information Module   IsapiModule
> >     Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler Handler   Mercurial-ISAPI Error
> >     Code    0x80004005 Requested URL    http://localhost:81/ Physical
> >     Path    C:\inetpub\hg Logon Method  Anonymous Logon User    Anonymous

What I need to setup for fix it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What versions of Python / Mercurial were you using?

I followed [these](http://www.firegarden.com/software/hosting-mercurial-repo-iis7-windows-server-2008r2-x64-python-isapi-cgi) instructions and got it to work with version 1.8.1 of Mercurial but I failed to get it to work with the latest version (1.9 at the time)